# Bootstrap 4: Cards: How do I make horizontal repeating cards in three columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make something like this:

card1 card2 card3
card4 card5 card6
card7 card8 card9
card10 card11 card12
card13 card14 card15
etc....(asp.net 
repeater control)

MEANING: Horizontal cards for Three columns.... So instead of vertically....I was the cards to go Horizontally FOR three columns (like a newspaper).

Comment: add .d-inline class to card div

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have an example?

Comment: If you want 3 columns you can simply add .col-sm-4 class to card. It will align 3 card x row

Comment: I don't know... I have three columns and it is repeating but within the first column. I am using this...                                                          
  <div class="card-columns">
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap">
    <div class="card card-block col-md-4">

Answer (score 2):

Use a single "row" div and put any number of "col-sm-4" divs inside. It will automatically break after 3 columns.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. The  <div class="col-sm-4"> isn't "sucking to the text" and has a lot of padding almost like it's trying to match the next cell but I can ask that question in another question. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .col-sm-4 class, that will align 3 divs containing card block per row

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      Your card
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: It's not working. Yes it makes it horizontal but it does this 1 under that is  2 under that is 3 then next to that is 4. I want it 1,2,3 then next line, 4,5,6.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this via the flex box properties. Either use your own or the ones provided by bootstrap.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div class="card card-block col-md-4">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{prod.title}}</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{{prod.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Do this as many times as you need -->
</div>
```